# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR on all images with a pwa hosted on OVH web Cloud

Tags: express, http2, ovh

As the title says i have a PWA hosted on OVH webcloud with ssl activated.

The requests are made with h2 protocol which leads to `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` on all static images of the website.

I've tried :

- Activate CDN (seemed to have solved the issue for certains persons on forums)
- To check the disk free size (not a problem)
- deactivate HTTP/2 via the `.htaccess` file
- deactivate gzip vie the `.htaccess` file

None of this worked i'm out of ideas.

Do you have any ?